# unfortunately,welcome stopped working in android

Tags: android

I have tried to do a project in android studio by connecting to sqlite.which simply stores age and name when button is pressed.but it is stopping..

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.pallavi.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void onButtonClick(View v){

        EditText a=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        String str=a.getText().toString();

        if(v.getId()==R.id.Bdisplay)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Display.class);
            i.putExtra("Username",str);
            startActivity(i);

        }

        if(v.getId()==R.id.SignInButton)
        {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignUp.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is Connectdb.java where i used for get and set.
Connectdb.java

```
package com.example.pallavi.welcome;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by pallavi on 12/5/15.
 */
public class Connectdb extends Activity {

    String name,age;



    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

code of main activity xml page from here i take inputs:
activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Age"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.pallavi.welcome;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by pallavi on 12/5/15.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=3;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="students.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="students";
    private static final String COLOUMN_ID="id";
    private static final String COLOUMN_NAME="name";
    private static final String COLOUMN_AGE="age";
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table students (id integer primary key not null auto_increment,"+"name text not null,age text not null); ";

   public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
   {
       super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.db=db;



    }

    public void insertContact(Connectdb c)
    {
       db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLOUMN_NAME,c.getName());
        values.put(COLOUMN_AGE,c.getAge());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);

    }


}
```

and it is even saying too much output to process
error in logcat is:

```
  05-15 14:29:52.924    1869-1869/com.example.pallavi.welcome E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "auto_increment": syntax error
05-15 14:29:52.929    1869-1869/com.example.pallavi.welcome E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pallavi.welcome, PID: 1869
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "auto_increment": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table students (id integer primary key not null auto_increment,name text not null,age text not null);
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
            at com.example.pallavi.welcome.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:29)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.example.pallavi.welcome.DatabaseHelper.insertContact(DatabaseHelper.java:38)
            at com.example.pallavi.welcome.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:39)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: filter logcat by the name of your app and post the relevant error

Comment: i got error more than the limit to paste those are the errors which appeared for this logcat especially

Comment: it is because you didn't filter logcat

Comment: i have filtered my logcat and pasted error....now try to check it and solve the error ...kindly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a syntax error in creating table, as also understandable by error in your logcat. Try replacing `auto_increment` by `AUTOINCREMENT`, which is the right keyword in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Your Logcat says

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "auto_increment": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table students (id integer primary key not null auto_increment,name text not null,age text not null);

It should be `autoincrement` and not auto_increment.

Answer (score 0):

The error you've posted clearly says:

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "auto_increment":
 syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:
 create table students (id integer primary key not null auto_increment,name text not null,age text not null);
```

So, the source of error is in the following string:

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table students (id integer primary key not null auto_increment,"+"name text not null,age text not null); ";
```

The query is wrong and should be (please note, that `autoincrement` keyword should be right after `integer primary key`):

```
create table students (id integer primary key autoincrement not null, name text not null,age text not null);
```

For more details take a look [here](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: nikis i am facing a problem for inserting data from my app to sqlite and retreiving it..do you have any sample code...i have refferd to several videos but still unable to do..please provide me procedure too

Comment: @MuraliKrishna have you tried to make the edits from this answer